# Qtvirtualkeyboard not showing in application

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtvirtualkeyboard

Here is my problem, I have want to use the qt virtual keyboard. I have it working on the desktop but on my raspberrypi3 (running minimal root filesystem) it does not pop up.

I have put

```cpp
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
```

in main.cpp

and have put the InputPanel in main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1

Item {
    id: root
    Item {
        id: appContainer
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: inputPanel.top
        //...
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel;
        y: parent.height; // position the top of the keyboard to the bottom of the screen/display

        anchors.left: parent.left;
        anchors.right: parent.right;
        Component.onCompleted: {
            inputPanel.keyboard.style.languagePopupListEnabled = false;
        }
        states: State {
            name: "visible";
            when: inputPanel.active;
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel;
                // position the top of the keyboard to the bottom of the text input field
                y: parent.height - inputPanel.height;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use it on the rp3 it does not appear. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have the Virtual Keyboard plugin installed at the target platform?

Comment: Okay I made some progress. I have to load the qml file. I did that, and depending on what I do either I get a white square or nothing. This is on my home machine.    So how does one load the qml file?